# Excel columns made up of different merged cells

Tags: regex, excel

I'm trying to tidy up a sheet  with the following problem, and would appreciate any advice.

My sheet has 7 "master columns" and about 4000 rows. It was compiled by converting a load of PDF documents.
The master columns are made up of merged minor columns, but at various parts of the data, the minor columns that make up each master column are different.
eg The first master column is made up of merged columns A-H for the first 30 rows, but for the next 25 rows it's made up of merged columns A-G etc.

As I said, overall there are still the same 7 master columns from top to bottom, but the merging is different throughout...

Can anyone think of a way to fix this without doing it all manually?

Comment: Do you want to unmerge?

Comment: ideally yes. but essentially I want to get to a position where the data that corresponds to each master column title is in the same column throughout the sheet (whether that's a merged column or an unmerged column, I don't mind so much).

Comment: here's an image illustrating the problem http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/1643/bqf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your horrible spreadsheet into Word with Home > Clipboard – Paste, Paste Special, Unformatted Text and replace `^t^t` with `^t`. Replace All repeatedly, until `Word has completed its search of the document and has made 0 replacements`. Copy back in to Excel.

This is not tested on your image so there might be some issues – perhaps column misalignments (where even Word’s limited regex may help to add back tabs where suitable). The result should be no merged cells – mind you someone on SE described these along the lines of “A creation of the Devil to test us beyond endurance” (ie best avoided).

Comment: this almost worked but in the end i fixed by unmerging, selecting all, F5 > special > select blanks. delete and shift left.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the full document and click unmerge button from the ribbon.

As per the screen shot you provided, you can select all and unmerge but getting the corresponding fields in order might be challenging.

Try using macros to set combined functionalities in a single or combine key presses

Comment: yep have tried that - unfortunately it doesn't help. - rows 1-10 will have data in column A, then 6 blank columns before data in column H, while rows 11-20 will have data in column A, then 4 blank columns before data in column F

Comment: Most probably you have to do it the long way. Macros with short cut keys could help

Comment: Have you tried selecting the small table below the large table and using paste special to 'paste values only' to another sheet.

Comment: i've just realised that when unmerged, the cells with data in have a white background, and the blank cells have no background colour... is there a way of mass deleting only cells with no background colour